# How to Consume a Post Request w/ json (Web API c#)

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a strange issue.  I am trying to consume a json object from a post (made in postman):

```
POST /api/orders/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61595
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1b628111-4498-e175-733b-00172ad529d6

{
   "Fname" : "Jonathan",
   "Lname" : "Barker",
   "OrderItem" : "64734"
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
// POST: api/Orders
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var oMycustomclassname =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(value);
    }
```

In debug value is null.  I am sure I am missing something simple.  Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: why does you api controller action take a string vs. the actual object?

Comment: @Fran Fran thanks for your question, Can you give me an example of the controller action with an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a class for your parameter:

```
class Order
{
    public string OrderItem {get;set;}
    public string Fname {get;set;}
    public string Lname {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can change `string` to `Order` in your API parameter:

```
// POST: api/Orders
public void Post([FromBody]Order value)
{
    //value already contains Lname, Fname, and OrderItem.
    //Access it like this: value.Lname
}
```

Comment: That did it!  Quick follow up Jeric:

Comment: How can I handle a more complex Json like

    {"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}